# Как сделать чтобы функция применялась только к конкретно выбраному элементу?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, есть такой код

```
    div class="hidden_edit_form"
      = render "answers/quick", answer: answer
```

Он рендерит форму для редактирования ответа:

```
= form_for answer do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id
  .field
     = f.label :text
     = f.text_area :text
  .actions = f.submit
```

Выходит что на страничке есть например 10 ответов на вопрос.
Изначально они скрыты из-за класса - hidden_edit_form. Под каждым ответом есть кнопка "Edit". 
Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку открывалась форма редактирования только для этого ответа?
Сейчас такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show_edit_form").click(function(){
        $(".hidden_edit_form").show();
    });
});
```

Он отображает все формы для всех ответов сразу, а не только для конкретно выбранного. Короче говоря срабатывает для всех форм скрытых под классом hidden_edit_form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Использовать параметр [event](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) передаваемый по умолчанию для метода [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/). У параметра event есть атрибут [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".show_edit_form").click(function(event){
          buttonEl = $(event.target); //кнопка на которую нажали
          /* тут должен быть код для нахождения нужной формы рядом с нажатой кнопкой
             к примеру (при условии что у формы и кнопки общий родитель):
             var form = buttonEl.siblings('hidden-edit-form');
          */
          form.show();
       });
   });
   ```
2. Использовать уникальные классы для форм редактирования и кнопок. Аналогично первому, с помощью event.target узнать какая именно кнопка была нажата. Понять к какой форме она относится к примеру к форме с иденитификатором 9 `class="edit-button-9"`. 
   После этого найти форму с классом `class="hidden-edit-form edit-form-9"`

P.S. названия классов взяты из головы. Если вы сторонник id то никто не мешает использовать их вместо классовю

Comment: маловероятно, что нажатая кнопка находится в невидимой форме

Comment: @igor да вы правы. не подумал когда писал пример, в принципе сути это не меняет но поправлю

Comment: в обработчиках `jQuery` _this_ так же указывает на нужный элемент

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался)